# selinux boolean allow_user_postgresql_connect has no effect

Tags: linux, postgresql, selinux

I'm setting up a new system which contains a postgresql database and I'm trying to lock down which machines are able to open a connection to the database.

I'm trying to use the allow_user_postgresql_connect boolean to achieve this but so far have been unable to get it to block any connections.

I am testing with 2 servers DB and Client as below.  Both are RHEL6u2 running postgres 8.4.7-2;

```
DB# getenforce
Enforcing
DB# getsebool allow_user_postgresql_connect
allow_user_postgresql_connect --> on
DB# service postgresql start
starting postgresql service:              [  OK  ]

Client# getenforce
Enforcing
Client# getsebool allow_user_postgresql_connect
allow_user_postgresql_connect --> off

Client-> psql -h DB "sslmode=require dbname=mydb" postgres
connects
```

I've tried all combinations of allow_user_postgresql_connect on/off on the two machines havent been able to cause it to deny a connection.

How should this bool be set to prevent a user on a machine from connecting to the database?

I'm very new to SElinux so may be overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to use SELinux for this?  Postgres already has [a perfectly cromulent authentication and authorization system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), which is what you should be using for this (among other reasons, because it puts failed logins in the logical place: the Postgres logs).

If you are trying to further secure the system by not letting unauthorized systems connect to the Postgres port at all then presumably you have a list of authorized systems (IP addresses), and can configure a firewall rule that blocks traffic from unauthorized hosts.

Trying to wrestle SELinux into submission for something like this seems like trying to drive a square peg into a credit card slot to me.

Comment: (incidentally [from a description of `allow_user_postgresql_connect`](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans) I don't think that flag does what you think it does: It seems to determine if the *user* can connect to the Postgres port, not whether the Postgres daemon should be accepting connections.  Seems essentially worthless to me given the above in any case...)

Comment: Yeah, the boolean permits processes running in the user domain on the DB server to connect to the socket.

Comment: That was also my initial idea of what the boolean was intended do (limit on the client it's ability to connect) as it makes little sence to have a db that doesn't accept ANY connections.  I have it configured as it is in the question as I'm trying to prove that it STOPs the connection.  To your original post, that is correct and where possible I'll be using firewalls to prevent connections, but in the interest of multiple layers of security (and as a learning exercise) I want to get selinux working as well.

Comment: @kernelpanic, Does this mean the boolean can only have a local affect?  I.E it is only valid for limiting users on the DB server connecting to that DB?

Comment: @TaninDirect Correct -- the boolean only affects the machine it's set on. It's useful for enforcing a site policy ("this machine should never even attempt to connect to Postgres"), though such policy is properly enforced on the server as I described above.  It might also briefly inconvenience someone who has broken into the local machine, but at that point they can just copy the `$PGDATA` directory and they've got your DB anyway...

Comment: +1 for cromulent usage of the word `cromulent`.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this in the future, go with the original answer and be happy with other metods of securing the DB.  I haven't been able to get this working even for local accounts on the DB server.